# Business acronym usage in source code

Tags: programming-practices

What are the rules about acronym usage that are related to the business ?

I always hesitate between using the acronym or not. When talking with people who work here they will understand faster when I use the acronym. On the other hand using the full name helps me when I still need to learn what the acronym means.

For example, in electricity, SCCR is a pretty well known acronym. But I didn't know that it mean "Short-Circuit Current Rating". So I wanted to put the full name in my class.

Another example, FLA, meaning "Full-load amperage" is now something registered in my brain, so I simply put the acronym in my classes.

But since I'm trying that the code is clear for everyone who reads it I think I should always use the full name instead of acronyms. But it happened in the past that a developer used the full name and the business user didn't understand what the developer was talking about! Maybe in this example, the problem was something else...

Comment: You can't really make a general rule about this, it will depend on the particular domain and project. Don't make up acronyms to save typing, but if an acronym is well established in the domain it is fine to use in code (but be consistent - don't spell it out in some identifiers and shorten in others).

Comment: Will the next developer(s) know all the acronyms? Or will they too have to learn them? It may be useful to the next developer to use explicit names.

Comment: "I'm trying that the code is clear for everyone who reads it" - that's good, but you can go overboard. You have to find a balance, so consider who your "readership" is. If you're writing code for an internal project in a certain domain, there's going to be a lot of domain-specific lingo and concepts that will appear in your code (including a certain amount of acronyms). This will make the code understandable to those involved in the project, and will also make it more expressive and more concise, but it will make it less understandable to a more general audience - and that's fine.

Answer (score 5):

"Write your code like the developer who maintains it is a violent psychopath who knows where you live".

A couple of rules I try to adhere to wrt domain specific acronyms/initialisms:

- **Dis-ambiguate**: Meet with your stakeholders to work out and define any ambiguous language. 'Monies' might sound universal, but could have a very specific meaning for certain businesses.
- **Keep domain specific language in the domain it represents**. Try to not let something like 'FLA' leak everywhere in your code and try to ensure that it stays close to the true data it represents.
- **Document Your Code**. If you are compelled to let an acronym leak, try to ensure that there's some documentation close to it that calls it out.
- **Leverage your IDE**.  Code completion is cheap, use it. IDE's like Jetbrains even provide Camel-Case completion: 'FLARF' can be used to trigger autocomplete for something like `FullLoadAmperageReducerFactory`

Comment: yeah I agree with your last statement about code completion. it is a reason why I don't mind using very long name for clarity because it does not reduce my coding speed.

Comment: These are good tips, but I feel like they're more related to language that is coined _because of_ the application. OP is asking about things that within the business context are well-established concepts. If e.g. SCCR is so well-established that everyone involved in the business knows about it, and it was not coined by the developers, then the developers should not be defining it in their documentation. That's a big if, but based on OP's question it does seem like that's the case here.

Comment: To add an exaggerated example to @Flater's comment, if you showed me a piece of code that has a `HyperTextTransportProtocolUniformResourceIdentifier` type and a `HyperTextMarkupLanguage` or `CascadingStyleSheets` builder, I would question your sanity. When it comes to web application technical jargon, "HTTP", "URI", "HTML", or "CSS" are *not* "acronyms" that need to be explained and expanded, they are just "words". And the same is true for other domains, too. In my domain, nobody expands SDI, HD, UHD, MADI, or AES, and "2110-20" is a term everybody understands.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right, they're not acronyms, they're _initialisms_.  :-D Pedantics aside, the point is that _if_ there is ambiguity, it needs to be cleared. HTML/CSS are ubiquitous until they aren't. Even Google and Apple have so many initialisms that they  conflicts at times. That nobody expands UHD, MADI, et al in your domain is because their is no ambiguity and so long as those terms are transparently understood by anyone new on the project? You're g2g. The domain restriction is b/c seeing references to HTML/CSS in your DL or AES in your FE or in any BDD is probably OOP.

Comment: @Flater Any business specific app will at some point be required to reflect the Business Domain and that means using Business Language, Developers are often operating _apart_ from that domain, reflecting and representing it while not (necessarily) participating. It happens more in consulting but also  in-house. At some point, devs need to communicate and clarify intent with their stakeholders and that's a lot easier if everyone is on the same page.  To that end, _when_ SCCR is inevitably used in code to model something, it's going to be important for the reader to understand that model.

Comment: @incongruentDoughnut _"To that end, when SCCR is inevitably used in code to model something, it's going to be important for the reader to understand that model."_ The point I'm making is that based on OP's scenario, it seems that the reader already understands this concept. There's no additional developer documentation needed to explain to the reader something that was already clear from the surrounding business context. This question is centered around whether already known abbreviations should be used in code, not how to explain unknown abbreviations to a reader.

Comment: @Flater From OP: _"I didn't know that it [SCCR] means 'Short-Circuit Current Rating'."_ That doesn't sound like OP understanding the concept _until they were taught_. You're also harping on ONE point as if it was the only solution instead of recognizing it as just a piece of the solution. So to other points, we don't _know_ that SCCR should even _be_ in code. That might be a Commercial Term or maybe it's a reference to a strict eng specification or maybe it's proprietary. That's all a part of the disambiguating and that also pertains to Domain Specific Language use.

Comment: @incongruentDoughnut: You're right that this is contextual to the situation. Based on OP calling it a "pretty well known acronym", however, it seems likely that its definition is understood to the degree that the developers are not the ones who are having to relay its meaning to its readers. But, as you point out, that is only one possible outcome and OP's question does not contain enough information for me to claim that this is conclusively the case - it is a gut feeling based on how OP wrote their question.

Comment: @Flater I don't even entirely disagree with you, just trying to explain it for anyone who might come after.  Re: "pretty well known", I want to say yes, but I've been in too many places where 'pretty well known' is just shared tribal knowledge and that's rarely a good sign.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possibilities:

- Write a project glossary in a text file and check it in with the project. Now everyone can look up "FLA" if they're uncertain
- Many textual style guides have an expand-on-first-use rule. So at the top of the file defining FLA objects you'd have "FLA (Full load amperage)" in a comment
- Use the comments or "javadoc"-like system: put the abbreviation in the name and the full name in the comment at the top of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The only rule is whatever your manager sets for the codebase.

Let's try to think rationally about the consequences of using the acronyms:

- Code is more succinct. Without the acronym, would it be unacceptably long?
- People who know the acronyms may get lost in the acronym soup anyway if there's too many. Are the acronyms actually used frequently? Do people who know the acronyms still have to stop and look them up when reading code?
- People who don't know the acronyms will get very confused. Are you very certain that all programmers in the future will also be electrical engineers?
- Acronyms are hard to learn. When you Google the acronym, do you get useful results? Is it spelled out somewhere, like a header comment or at first usage?

You can see that each acronym is a tradeoff and must be judged case by case.

Comment: The OP could well be the senior member of his function - therefore there would be no higher manager to ask about these questions.

Comment: Exactly, I'm the senior in my team and I'm currently building coding rules for the team to use. With all the response here, I'm definitely going for no acronyms or the acronyms needs to be very well documented.

Comment: @Steve What is the confusion, exactly? My first sentence is still valid even if he's the manager. You just have to mentally swap the noun.

Comment: @gomennathan, on first read I interpreted it primarily to be a suggestion that he refer to his own manager for explanation on "the rules", hence my remark that whilst many may have managers, many of those managers will have no software design experience. On second read, it may be that you were really saying "there are no rules, unless your own manager has set some", which is true, but it would still be at cross purposes to the OP who clearly meant "rules" in the sense of "design guidelines and considerations", not in the sense of "organisational strictures" - so there *are* rules.

Answer (score 1):

For class names I do not see a valid reason to ever abbreviate them. Mind that class names do not occur that often in your logic. You create an instance using the class name and then continue to use the variable identifier, which could be the abbreviation.

If there is no need to leave people guessing or to force them to look up the meaning of some term, don't.

Answer (score 0):

For industry-standard acronyms, or obvious contractions of common terminology, there is no rule against them.

For example, nobody is likely to complain about "GL" to mean "general ledger" or "Bal" to mean "balance".

However, naming schemes are always context-dependent, depending on how many different things need to be distinguished in a context, how familiar the terminology is likely to be to a developer, how obvious it is to a developer that they are in a particular terminological context, and so on.

For example, anyone familiar with Dilbert will probably guess easily enough what TLAs from PHBs are, but it would be easy to struggle not only for those unfamiliar with Dilbert, but also for anyone not realising that the context is Dilbert.

Comment: Honestly seeing "Bal" for balance would fill me with rage. Shortening words to me is the worst offense of all, IMO

Comment: I'd offer a different viewpoint. there is *no* reason to use "GL" when you could use "Ledger" as class name or "GeneralLedger". There is also no reason to use "gl" as variable name when you can also use "general_ledger" or "generalLedger". Code is more often read than written, keep it accessible. "Bal" is even worse. Saving those few characters won't give you *any* improvement in actual readability or any other benefit and only downsides.

Comment: @whatsisname, for those of us who deal primarily in tables of data, abbreviations for column headers are unfortunately the rule.

Comment: @Polygnome, on the contrary, abbreviations for column headers can massively improve the information density of tables, and the readability and usability as a result. Even in object oriented code, I've seen long names go too far, causing code clutter. Judicious abbreviations very much promote readability.

Comment: What Kind of "Table Headers" are you talking about there? For UI i agreed, you could Label them in Domain palance. But internally in your source Code, e.g. Database Schemata, I See little reason to overdo IT.

Comment: @Polygnome, it's not about "domain parlace" (i.e. aligning with anyone else's customary lingo), it's about maximising the useful information on a screen showing a table (where you can't just go infinitely rightwards with column headers), and it's about my needs as someone handling source code. In more complicated database work, it's easy to blow through say 30 characters in naming, and that's with abbreviations, because a large number of subtleties often have to be distinguished. (1/2)

Comment: I would always encourage people to err on the side of longhand certainly, but I cannot accept a rule against abbreviations as sensible advice, and I've seen terribly unreadable code which goes to the other extreme, where structural and logical features of code are overwhelmed by the bulk of excessive names (without the ontological complexity justifying such waffle), and where the length and diversity of those names destroys shape recognition of words or any guidance on where to target the centre field of the eyes. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve You can take *any* reasonable advice and turn it absurd if you want to. If your variable names approach 30 characters, I'm pretty sure they aren't *concise* enough anymore. Readability is always a trade-off. In another context, I'd say its reasonable to have local variable m and a and calculate F = m * a, because thats whats easily accessible to domian experts (physicists).

Comment: However, there is little reason to name a class "GL" when you could just name it "GeneralLedger". Context is important. Stuff like "var gl = new GeneralLedger()" might be completely fine, although I'd argue you could also name the variable more descriptively. For table columns, you make some good points (screen real estate), but I'd argue that when you work with those values in your code again, you *do* have the screen real estate to assign them t more descriptive names again. As always, optimize for readability.

Comment: @Polygnome, as long as we accept that abbreviations and acronyms are acceptable in principle, then that's all. I wouldn't use "Bal" in a context where I could easily use Balance *consistently throughout the whole context*, but once you have a series of balances covering various periods or calculated in different ways, and different units of measure, then names can be required to start carrying a lot of weight. And once the abbreviations have to be used sometimes, you may as well be consistent. "Num", "Amt", "Id", "Ref" - there are many examples that should be uncontroversial. (1/2)

Comment: Also my assumption with the General Ledger example (as well as the others) was that GL would be used widely as a prefix or an element of a name, not that a freestanding thing would be abbreviated down to just GL (except, as you say, a local variable). In hindsight that was perhaps not clear. My primary purpose when I wrote the answer was to emphasise that things should not be abbreviated down into ambiguity, by using obscure or thoughtlessly contrived abbreviations of a personal nature (as distinct from the common abbreviations I gave). (2/2)